# With a Pandememic grounding many to their residence.... How to maintain flight hours?

Tags: general-aviation, faa, regulations, pilot-certification

No matter your Country, is grounding affecting license requirements(Passenger, Cargo or even Private) and how are the hours being rectified. CNN actually posed a great question in this article and I am also curious to know if this has been addressed CNN: What happens when pilots don't get their flying hours?.
https://www.cnn.com/travel/article/pilots-recency-flying-hours/index.html

Comment: Are you only interesting by FAA? Moreover, if your question is specific to the covid19 pandemic, you should precise it (each drop in airline traffic may have different causes -e.g. volcan ashes-, impact the industry differently -cf cargo flight vs passenger flights vs GA-  and thus each responses by EASA, FAA, ... are not the same)

Comment: I am trying to get at hrs req's for any Country or cargo to passenger really, this shutdown causes license issues and I am wondering how that is being considered.

Comment: You should edit the question to include your last comment. I'm not sure you are asking for any country. There are country with few international flight and/or no commercial flights (e.g. Eritrea, North Korea). On my side, I'm more worried for GA. You can also consider edit tags if you are interested by not only FAA regulations

Comment: Note that cargo are not as affected as passengers by grounding due to covid19. Almost all international flights are cargo (med supplies and other shipping).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many countries are extending validation periods, but ultimately it's a question that isn't fully answered yet. Right now the focus is on the pandemic - the practical concequences come second.

Chances are it will be a combination of extending legally mandated periods, and common sense by operators.